# nginx systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

as relevant with current times so i'm installing myself a mastodon instance...

when I try to restart nginx i get the error

```
root@instance-20221113-1925:/home/ubuntu# sudo systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
```

here's the log (it says `Nov 13 09:45:11 instance-20221113-1925 nginx[34044]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`):

https://pastebin.com/bRxTA3m1

the conf file is (unedited):

https://pastebin.com/dcK2RyCH

can an experienced eye spot an error? thank you!

Comment: found the workaround here:

Comment: Not a workaround. Linked configuration above is incomplete. Next time try `nginx -t` to get a more specific analysis of the config.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove nginx first and reinstall it.

List packages installed related to nginx, and remove them.

```bash
dpkg --get-selections | grep nginx

sudo apt --purge remove nginx
sudo apt --purge remove nginx-common
sudo apt --purge remove nginx-core
```

And install nginx again

```bash
sudo apt install nginx
```

And now when I run `systemctl status nginx`, the service is active.
[successfully started nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk5g5.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there's a missing ssl_certificate directive for the listen ... ssl directive in the configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mastodon at line 25.

```
Nov 13 09:44:42 instance-20221113-1925 nginx[34033]: nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mastodon:25
Nov 13 09:44:42 instance-20221113-1925 nginx[34033]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Nov 13 09:44:42 instance-20221113-1925 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
```

try this

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name your_domain.com;

        ssl_certificate <<<<<<<</path/to/your/certificate.pem>>>>>>>;
        ssl_certificate_key <<<<<<</path/to/your/private/key.pem;

        # Additional SSL configurations can be added here

        location / {
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            # proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            # proxy_buffering off;
            # proxy_request_buffering off;
            # proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            # proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            }
    }

}
```

Remember to replace your_domain.com with your actual domain name, and update the paths for ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key with the correct paths to your SSL certificate and private key files.

Answer (score -1):

Found the workaround here:
[certbot instructions fail with ssl_certificate error](https://github.com/mastodon/documentation/issues/940)

another addition to the instructions: at the end of IPtables setup run:

```
sudo iptables --flush
```